# Layout for on-screen hexadecimal keyboard

Tags: interaction-design, input, keyboard-layout

I am to design a web-based, on-screen keyboard for a touch interface. Users will only need to input 0-9 and the letters A-F. In addition to this, they need a backspace, and possibly a "clear" button. So, I have begun toying around by modifying [this keyboard](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-keyboard-with-css-and-jquery--net-5774) by Vasili.

My first proposal was this:

[image: Hexadecimal Keyboard Interface 1]

Which has an unnecessary dash and a space bar that is there more for tradition and coherence than anything else. So I decided it was not good enough. In removing the dash and the space bar, I would be left with 16 buttons, plus backspace. Now, 16 is pretty neat for ordering things, but 17 isn't. So, in adding a "clear" button, I thought of arranging the hex characters in a 4x4 pattern, and then having bigger "removal" buttons underneath:

[image: Hexadecimal Keyboard Interface 2]

But this still doesn't feel right! In particular, because mixing letters and numbers seems confusing. So then I thought: What if I put numbers on 2 rows of 5, and then add removal buttons onto one letter row of 3 each? And this is probably the one I'm the most satisfied with:

[image: eHexadecimal Keyboard Interface 3]

But I should probably flip the order, right? Starting the top row with 1, 2, etc. and the third row with A, B, etc.

Anyone else have a better idea?

Comment: I realize the need to restrict the characters used, but are any of these really better than a full keyboard for most users? Will anyone type enough on these keyboards to gain any fluency?

Comment: That's a valid point, I guess. Users will typically use the keyboard to type in booking numbers of ~10 characters. My thinking on restricting the size is of course to not clutter the UI. But I guess it might not feel much like cluttering to a user, as a keyboard is a very commonplace input device, so to speak.

Comment: Can I ask who your users are? Will they be using this keyboard often enough to get familiar with it?

Comment: @vincebowdren the platform will be used by a variety of vendors. But the typical use case is a person who is to retrieve a booking for some sort of event. So few users will use the keyboard more often than once every few weeks.

Comment: The order is 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0,A,B,C,D,E,F. Your second example is all over the place. The third one would be OK if flipped to 12345/67890/ABC/DEF as you suggest. But I like renaud's answer better.

Comment: I think an enter key would be useful. Sure, enter can be implied when sufficient digits have been entered, but every PIN entry device I have used at banks and shops has an enter key. I assume that part of the reason for this is that users like to pause and confirm. BTW, you can get a lot more inspiration for hexadecimal keypads if you google it.

Comment: Side notes: An example of historical usage can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:MPT0080K-1.PNG).  For modern usage, see [here](http://personal.stevens.edu/~backland/Courses/Course487_Spring_14_files/Labs/Lab4.pdf)

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Why don't simply improve the standard numerical keyboard by adding the missing characters ?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiq2m0.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Yes. Definitely keep the digits `0` to `9` in the "right" (calculator-style) order with zero at the bottom.

Comment: I'd keep the 0, backspace and clear on the bottom, numbers in the same order, but then swap the letters. ABC on the first line, DEF on the second line. Commonly I've seen letters top to bottom, numbers bottom to top.

Comment: @JackMcE No,no,no! This one gets my upvote because in addition to retaining the normal layout for the numbers, it is one of the few that has a consistent order for all 16 digits! Start at 0, then left to right, bottom to top. All the others are making my eyes hurt!

Comment: I like this, keep the numbers in the usual orientation. The only disadvantage is it's a little bit tall. Maybe the letter block could be moved beside 789/456 and made a different colour. That leaves the bottom right corner to spread out the backspace/ clear etc. It's OK to have a bit of unused space in an on-screen keyboard. It's not costing you extra money like it would in a real one.

Comment: +1 There's something to be said for _extending_ a familiar design (a calculator or numeric keypad) layout, rather than inventing something totally new. Note that if it was more important to extend a _telephone_ keypad (1-2-3 on top, with 0 in not in numerical order), it's not clear how you would want to lay out 0 and A-F. The "tallness" of the layout is a bit of a concern, but I think the basic familiarity outweighs that.

Comment: `A` is the next "digit" after `9` so in numeric keypad order it should be in the row right above nine, as Renaud has put it. Do **not** put ` A B C ` in a row with ` D E F ` **below** it. `+1`

Comment: The **HUGE** problem with design is the shape. It's narrow and extremely tall, so it gives a ratio that would fill up an entire display rather than being something that fills just the bottom half of the screen. I am assuming here that it's a virtual keyboard for mobile devices and there familiarity isn't half as important as it actually being easy to reach and practical in it's shape. This simply is not. In portrait it will give rise to weirdly wide buttons, in landscape it's just downright unusable. And as it's web-based there is not fixing rotation either.

Comment: Next, ignoring the shape problem there is the problem that normal users are not acquainted with hexidecimal numbers, so for the majority of the users the A is **not** a continuation after 9... thus giving rise to an alphabet that will feel to **normal** users the wrong way round, even if a lot of the programmers here (see +22 on steveverrill) will feel differently.

Comment: The (probably-started-as-a-joke) [IPv6-buddy keypad](http://www.ipv6buddy.com/) uses this design. Whether that's from UX research or because it was cheap to manufacture though I couldn't say.

Comment: This is [more or less the design of the Calculator app on OS X](http://i.stack.imgur.com/AQMhl.png) in Hex mode (it has dedicated `FF` and `00` buttons and the AC and C buttons are off to the side with the operators, but the number order is identical).

Comment: This is really neat, accepting this.

Answer (score 28):

You say the keyboard is for **hexadecimal** input. And that's the reason why your second try doesn't feel right! As @steveverrill also noticed in the comments, the numeric order `ABCDEF1234567890` is wrong. So if you want to go with a 4x4 layout, you should choose one of these:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ff36JR.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: The first one. Definitely.

Comment: @steveverrill: Yeah, probably. Because it's easier to detect the arrangement pattern? I wasn't sure why in the "standard numerical layout" the smaller digits were on the bottom.

Comment: Either Renaud's extended keypad (if the users are expecting calculator-style input) or your first one (if they aren't).

Comment: @Bergi smaller digits are more likely to occur in many empirical data sets ([Benford's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benford%27s_law)), an effect that is only increased by rounding. Putting the smaller digits closer to the bottom of a calculator might be a way to reduce hand travel. This is supported by the fact that on most calculator layouts the common operators trend towards the bottom (= usually being right at the bottom-right).

Comment: I think the second one is easier to get used to, mainly because that is the layout that a regular keyboard numpad uses.

Comment: 2nd one is very close (but not quite) to the standard numeric part of a PC keyboard, beyond that it's the classic telephone / calculator argument...

Comment: I would favor the above in those cases, and only those cases, where the upper and lower two bits of the hex value had "meaning".  For example, if the four bits of each value hex values were used to indicate whether objects could go up, down, left, and right, then having things in each row support the same horizontal movements and things in each column support the same vertical movement may be helpful.  On the other hand, most people entering numbers are going to prefer to have 1-9 in a 3x3 matrix.

Comment: The second one, because it more closely follows the current base-10 standard that everybody's used to.

Comment: I may have been wrong in calling it hexadecimal, in that while the "numbers" 0-F truly represent hexadecimal data, but that the end users will still think of letters and numbers as something fundamentally different here.

Answer (score 18):

So, as I was writing a couple of pretty long comments on the other answer, I felt inclined to present it as an answer as well. Following are a couple of considerations not made by the other major designs and mockups implementing these considerations:

## Mobile virtual keyboards shapes

Notice the shape keyboards take on mobile devices on the mockups drawn below:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftmDIo.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Any designs have to work in the restrictions of virtual keyboards. Now in this specific case the top whitespace may be a bit smaller, but still, the basic limitation still applies which rules out extremely tall designs for example.

## Rotation lock

Getting to the second point, mobile **web** apps can not limit the orientation. One could possibly do the following (as showing different content based on rotation is easy)

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSU0dk.png)</sup>

But I hardly believe anybody here would consider that proper UX design. In other words, we actually need two keyboard layouts: a portrait one and a landscape one.

## Normal users vs Programmers/Mathematicians

So, **programmers** will know about what hexadecimal codes are, normal users on the other hand will **not**. This is absolutely crucial, because it means the 'numbers' A to F should not be treated as numbers, but rather as letters. And letters are traditionally ordered alphabetically. Any design treating A-F as a continuation after 9 will only look good in the eyes of people aware of it's mathematical meaning, and from the question I understand that the users in this case are normal users entering a code that just happens to be hexadecimal.

## Portrait mockup

So, implementing those ideas gives something along the lines of (please note, this is just a possible implementation, some of the other implementations are just as valid, the main point of this post is the theory):

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsAylk.png)</sup>

I made two designs as I was torn between putting the letters and `[ok]` button to the left or right. The phone is held primarily in the right hand, so entering with one hand the numbers will be used more often than the `[ok]` button, **but** `[submit]` and `[enter]` like buttons tend to be to the right on desktop systems. Now I do believe that breaking this on mobile is within reason, but I am not sure it's worth the second look it will take.

## Landscape mockup

As with the above design the backspace and ok button could be mirrored to the other side, but at least it gets the concept across:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLSM4m.png)</sup>

Additionally I was torn between whether to start or end with the zero. Once again on traditional keyboards the zero comes at the end similar to the mockups, **but** when presented without the rest of the keyboard a strong argument could be made to count from 0 to 9.

Comment: *> mobile apps can not limit the orientation* Actually, it's certainly possible (on [Android](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20022003/1030702), [Windows Phone](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24109287/1030702) and [iPhones](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12283708/1030702)) for apps to simply disable rotation, or even specify a different orientation from the default. This means that you can design your layout for any single orientation without worrying about others if you don't want to. "Please rotate back" is a terrible solution unless you have no other options.

Comment: @Bob: We are talking about mobile web apps here, not sure why in the wide world you're trying to make a point by referring to the documentation for native apps...

Comment: Yea, sorry, forgot it was about webapps (was thrown off by your mention of mobile apps). You are correct there.

Answer (score 16):

Based on Renaud's idea of extending the standard numeric keypad, but wide instead of tall. Also illustrating that it's OK (even beneficial) to leave space between groups of keys.

```
+--------------------------------------------------+
|                                                  |
+--------------------------------------------------+

+-------+-------+-------+  +-------+-------+-------+
|   7   |   8   |   9   |  |   A   |   B   |   C   |
+-------+-------+-------+  +-------+-------+-------+
|   4   |   5   |   6   |  |   D   |   E   |   F   |
+-------+-------+-------+  +-------+-------+-------+
|   1   |   2   |   3   |                        
+-------+-------+-------+  +-------+-------+-------+
        |       0       |  | DEL.  | CLEAR | ENTER |
        +-------+-------+  +-------+-------+-------+
```

Comment: This get's my vote because it keeps both the the numbers and letters in a familiar pattern, it keeps them in numerical order (sort of, if you go up the left column then down the right column), and it's horizontal.

Comment: (No vote) but I don't like seperation  because I worry someone might think that they could type 10 on the keyboad for 10, (ie that the ABCDEF are optional). (as we know 0x10 is 16)

Could you improve your answers by either justerfying this risk, or by saying it won't happen because X (eg only experts would be in this mode)

Comment: @Oxinabox the OP's application is entering booking codes, which just happen to be hexadecimal numbers (many users won't even notice they are hexadecimal.) So I don't see the problem. Note that on the Windows calculator (see Halfwarr's answer) the letters and numbers have a different appearance, which I think helps, not hinders.

Answer (score 11):

Personally I like how the Windows Calculator does it:

[image]

I understand this does have extra keys that you do not need, but I do like having the letters in alphabetical order to the left of the keys. This also does not change the expected behavior for a keypad.

Comment: The idea here seems to have been to extend the standard calculator (rightmost five columns) by adding 3 columns to the left. I like the fact that the numbers are in the "normal" arrangement. Then again I may like this because I'm already used to using it.

Answer (score 9):

I noticed myself having to actualy search where were the numbers on your last two design.

I would definitely choose a design where the numbers are ordered and not mixed with letters.

Here is my attempt:

[image: Hexadecimal keyboard mockup design]

Here is another one, inspired by the default Windows calculator.

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
|                                               |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   A   |   D   |   6   |   7   |   8   |   9   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   B   |   E   |   2   |   3   |   4   |   5   |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|   C   |   F   |   0   |   1   | DEL.  | CLEAR |
+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+
```

I recommend distinguishing visually the letters from the numbers with this design (different background or font color), like the Windows one. But still, I find the first one more readable.

Edit: Added a picture made with balsamiq re-using @Renaud file

Comment: Your first one is the second best here (the best one being Renaud's) It has a couple of advantages: it's wide instead of tall, and it has all the letters in order. Colouring the numbers differently from the letters and del/clear would be a further enhancement. I don't like the second one at all.

Comment: @Renaud's design has the advantage of keeping the same digit order as the numpad, that's nice ! But i really find the keyboard too tall. Plus, as JackMcE noticed, some people prefer a different order for letters.

I really like the first one I made: easier to implement in a UI thanks to its horizontal look and keeps the number/letters organized.

Comment: Could the two downvoters explain why they think my answer is wrong? Please be constructive so I can improve!

Answer (score 8):

For what kind of screen is the interface? You say touch, but that can mean a multitude of things. For example, on a smartphone, a square-ish keyboard may be acceptable, but on a tablet  you want the width of the keyboard more than the height.

For a wide keyboard, I like steveverrill's idea (not enough points to upvote...), but I would tweak it a little bit like this:

```
+-------+-------+-------+  +-------+-------+
|   7   |   8   |   9   |  |   A   |   B   |
+-------+-------+-------+  +-------+-------+
|   4   |   5   |   6   |  |   C   |   D   |
+-------+-------+-------+  +-------+-------+
|   1   |   2   |   3   |  |   E   |   F   |                      
+-------+-------+-------+  +-------+-------+
| DEL.  |   0   |CLEAR  |  | Possibly Enter|
+-------+-------+-------+  +-------+-------+
```

Comment: Have an upvote for some more reputation ;-) I do think an enter key is a great advantage, for the reason I mentioned in my comment on the question.

Answer (score 5):

<sub>**Warning:** Unsubstantiated non-expert opinion ahead.</sub>

You say *hexadecimal keyboard* in your question, but **your users are not actually doing calculations with these numbers, or even really thinking of them as numbers at all**: they’re booking references, merely **alphanumeric codes**. They just happen to be alphanumeric codes which use only the first six letters of the alphabet.

The idea of expanding a numeric keypad to include the hexadecimal digits, as [suggested by Renaud](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/58473), would probably be excellent for people actually working with hexadecimal calculations, but for people merely typing in letters and numbers, I would keep the letters and the digits distinct. The wide layout [suggested by steveverrill](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/58505) seems the best for your use case: the numbers are in the standard layout of a numeric keypad, with which everyone is familiar, and the letters are separate and easy to find (there are only six of them, after all).

If you need a tall one, perhaps put the letters above the numbers, in a layout like Renaud’s, but separate the two with a gap, and perhaps a change of colour.

Answer (score 3):

I have two points to note about your layouts:

**I.** People are used to the existing decimal numpad layout for numbers, and I would not miss the opportunity to give the users the satisfaction of feeling familiar with this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftPjwm.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

**II.** Trying to force the extra characters in is not necessarily the best solution. I would try to group them in a way that makes them quick to use on their own.

Keeping with the "standard" of the numpad, two rows of three seems like the obvious choice for me. Also for some reason I want them to the right of the numpad, sort of giving them equal importance with the familiar numpad taking a little presidence.

The result is then:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqLuyn.png)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

A few constraints arise that direct our design:

- We want the number keys to be in the same order as we're all used to them being in.
- The keys should be located as close to each other as possible so that fingers travel the shortest distance when using the keypad.
- The 'clear' and 'backspace' keys should be located away from each other so that the user traverses a different qualitative direction to access that particular functionality.
- The 'clear' and 'backspace' keys should be located at outermost points (corners) to minimize accidental pressings.

With these constraints I've mocked-up a design comp that should fulfill your needs.

[image: Hex Keyboard Mock-Up]

I also think that a valid design could be moving the 'Clear' button to the top left so the top row reads "Clear, A, B, C".  Depends on which you like.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on the main post yet so I'll comment here.  @ChristoferOlafson: There are a couple questions I have about the design intended that would help us decide which (if any) of the current designs are appropriate:
--- Interestingly, no one has reproduced the fact that you have a 'read-out' at the top of your hex calc mock-up.  Is that a necessary aspect?
--- Are there further refinements of the interaction regarding the 'touch' requirement?  Should the Webapp work on all touch 'modes'?  (ie. Phone portrait/landscape, tablet portrait/landscape.) or a subset?

Comment: --- I suppose the larger question that would help greatly is: What is the application context in which the hex calculator is intended to be used?  How much other information must be easily visible while the calculator is active?

Answer (score 0):

Would it be possible to make the keys look like this... 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A/10, B/11, C/12, D/13, E/14, F/15, 0/16
I use hexadecimal dice, and this would be helpful in my app.

Comment: Can you do a mockup so we can see what you're suggesting?

Comment: These are **alphanumeric booking references**: no calculations are being done, and in the minds of the users, they aren't numbers at all. As such, any association between F and 16 is purely in the mind of the programmer: there is no need to show this to the user. It would only confuse them.